# How does TimeSpan.FromHours work?

Tags: c#

Hey everyone I want to know that working of get minutes from hours. 
I understand this:

```
test sample 1:-
    var result = TimeSpan.FromHours(2.5);
    var hours = (int)result.TotalHours;
    var minutes = result.Minutes;

output
    hours = 2
    minutes = 30
    it's calculate minute 6*5 = 30



test sample 2:-
        var result = TimeSpan.FromHours(2.123);
        var hours = (int)result.TotalHours;
        var minutes = result.Minutes;

    output
        hours = 2
        minutes = 7
        how it calculate minute = 7
```

please help me

Comment: You could [look up by yourself](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/timespan.cs,060fe8cc38e0a7e3).

Comment: Please clarify exactly what you're asking about here.

Answer (score 4):

When you're getting `TimeSpan` from hours with floats, the float part is considered as percentage of minutes in hour. Hour has 60 minutes, so 0.123 from 60 = 7 (12.3%).

Answer (score 0):

you are converting `2.5` and `2.123` to int and int will truncate the rest of the value after the `.` thats why you get `2`

the `30` comes from the `2.5`  because `0.5` is half which is `1/2` and `1/2 * 60 = 30`

same thing happens with the`.123` and the `7` minutes

Answer (score 0):

0.1 h  ->  6 min
0.2 h  ->  12 min
...
0.5 h  ->  30 min
...
1.0 h  ->  60 min   respectively    1h 0 min

See MSDN:

> **TimeSpan.Minutes**
>  Gets the minutes component of the time interval represented by the current TimeSpan structure.
>  Returns
>   **int**

and

> **TimeSpan.TotalMinutes**
>  Gets the value of the current TimeSpan structure expressed in whole and fractional minutes.
>  Returns
>   **double**

Comment: @Arsalan Qaiser `0.123` hours * 60 = `7.38` minutes

Answer (score 0):

Internally, `TimeSpan` holds the duration as a single long, in units of `100 nanoseconds`. It calls these `ticks`.

The implementation defines the following constants:

```
    public const long    TicksPerMillisecond =  10000;
    private const double MillisecondsPerTick = 1.0 / TicksPerMillisecond;

    public const long TicksPerSecond = TicksPerMillisecond * 1000;   // 10,000,000
    private const double SecondsPerTick =  1.0 / TicksPerSecond;         // 0.0001

    public const long TicksPerMinute = TicksPerSecond * 60;         // 600,000,000
    private const double MinutesPerTick = 1.0 / TicksPerMinute; // 1.6666666666667e-9

    public const long TicksPerHour = TicksPerMinute * 60;        // 36,000,000,000
    private const double HoursPerTick = 1.0 / TicksPerHour; // 2.77777777777777778e-11

    public const long TicksPerDay = TicksPerHour * 24;          // 864,000,000,000
    private const double DaysPerTick = 1.0 / TicksPerDay; // 1.1574074074074074074e-12
```

When you create a `TimeSpan` from a number of hours, it simply performs something similar to the following calculation (I've simplified this a bit from the actual code by removing the rounding and error checking code):

`long _ticks = (long)(hours * TicksPerHour);`

When you ask a `TimeSpan` for `TotalMinutes` it converts the ticks to minutes as follows:

```
    public double TotalMinutes {
        get { return _ticks * MinutesPerTick; }
    }
```

There's nothing at all complicated going on here.